# Magento backend form not loading

Tags: php, magento

For a magento webshop I am developing I'm having some problems with the customer and user edit form. The form won't show up in the HTML at all. And therefor is not displayed.

What I have tried:

- Disabling local modules
- Replacing customer.xml with a version from a working Magento installation
- Replacing the adminhtml customer.phtml files with versions from a working Magento installation
- Clearing cache
- Emptying the /var/ directory
- Enabling errors (None showing)
- Upping the memory limit

I'm starting to run out of options and am about to reinstall the webshop. Anyone got any clue?!

[image]

Comment: I'm failing to undestand your question please supply screen shots so I can understand better, what server are you running ?

Comment: have u edit core customer controller for admin

Comment: No I didn't (more chars)

Comment: have u edit any core block,model files.
Just replace core/mage/adminhtml/block/customer and controller helper model files

Comment: Nope, all default core, block and model files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved: It was a extension. I went trough all of them and disabled one by one until I found the source of the problem.